# Why isn't react-tap-event-plugin working in my TypeScript project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to work with `material-ui` and `react-tap-event-plugin` but I am getting this error when the app is loaded:

```
react-dom.js:18238 Warning: Unknown prop `onTouchTap` on <button> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see https://....
  in button (created by EnhancedButton)
  in EnhancedButton (created by IconButton)
  in IconButton (created by AppBar)
  in div (created by Paper)
  in Paper (created by AppBar)
  in AppBar (created by AppLayout)
  in div (created by AppLayout)
  in div (created by AppLayout)
  in AppLayout
  in MuiThemeProvider
```

This is my `index.tsx` file:

```
import * as injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();//I am able to get into this in the js debugger

ReactDOM.render(....)
```

This is my `index.html` file:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",

    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules" // don't run on any code in the node_modules directory
  ]
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "affiliate_portal_client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^15.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-tap-event-plugin": "0.0.30",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Here is the [entire source code](https://bitbucket.org/avifatal/public-portal/src/047d385d6c0b69078b62065f9f3fe00013e4acfe/AffiliatePortal.Client.MVC/src/?at=master) on BitBucket.

I'm sure what the problem is because the debugger shows that `injectTapEventPlugin` is invoked, so why am I getting an error?

Comment: can you recreate a repo with minimal code that produce the same error?

Comment: @Kafo https://bitbucket.org/avifatal/public-portal/src/047d385d6c0b69078b62065f9f3fe00013e4acfe/AffiliatePortal.Client.MVC/src/?at=master

Comment: I think the problem is in your import statement... Try `import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin'`

Comment: @DavidGomez this will bring the error `react-tap-event-plugin/index"' has no default export.` , but if I see the method is invoked isn't that mean that the import is ok? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the two `<script>`s you have in your `index.html`:

```
<script src="/node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

There is no point in including them because both `react` and `react-dom` are already included as dependencies in your `package.json`. Next get rid of your `externals` from `webpack.config.js`:

```
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
}
```

Since you're not using `<script>`s to include `react` and `react-dom` there is no reason to have them.

The call `injectTapEventPlugin` injects the custom events and props to elements and must be called with `react-dom` to correctly apply and inject the props. The following lines [in the source](https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin/blob/master/src/injectTapEventPlugin.js#L23-L25):

```
require('react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub').injection.injectEventPluginsByName({
  'TapEventPlugin':       require('./TapEventPlugin.js')(shouldRejectClick)
});
```

Inject the plugin directly into *the copy `react-dom` you installed in `package.json`*, at the path `node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js`, *not `node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js`*.

Since you include the dependencies twice, the injection to the copy `react-dom` in the `package.json` is **overridden**. Thus, when you include it with `<script>`s and you see the error because the copy from `<script>` doesn't have the plugin injected. Getting rid of the `<script>`s from `index.html` will get rid of this secondary inclusion and stop the injection from being overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like to be caused by referencing React in both index.html and webpack.config.js. Remove the following 2 lines from  webpack.config.js:

```
externals: {
    "react": "React",      // remove this
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"    // remove this
},
```